# Can not install matplotlib on python 2.7

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I tried to install matplotlib 2.2.4 on centos 7.4 , and I run `setup.py install`, The erros is

> "error: can't copy 'lib/matplotlib/backends/web_backend/jquery-ui-1.12.1': doesn't exist or not a regular file."

But the lib/matplotlib/backends/web_backend/jquery-ui-1.12.1 exists.

So who can tell me what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening when the package_data glob happens to match a directory. You need to re-write `setup.py` and change the name of your package to fix it.

Package_data assumes every name matched in the glob is a file, it confuses files and directories.

Modify your setup.py as below:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='xxx',
      version='0.1',

      packages=[
          'package',
      ],
      package_data={
          'package': [
              '*.dat',
              'dir/*'
      ],
  },
 )
```

You just need to change the name of the `package_data`. If the package name is `*` just add `.dat` after it.

Comment: But the setup.py try to copy the file from lib/matplotlib/backends/web_backend/jquery-ui-1.12.1 and this directory has already existed. Why did it say this dir doesn't exist or not a regular file.

Comment: don't you have a "package_data" part ?

Comment: I've run into the same issue, and don't understand the fix. The setup.py for matplotlib doesn't have the an obvious package_data glob. This answer seems to be assuming that the setup.py is for the user's package, rather than for matplotlib.